# Running tunneled IPv6 in Windows 8.1 without gogo6 Client

Tags: networking, windows-8, ipv6, tunnel

I have just discovered that my ISP (`IT Fastweb`) provides IPv6 services to home users.

Willing to try out connectivity, I have read their page about configuring IPv6 with gogo6 client. Their [guide](https://translate.google.it/translate?sl=it&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=it&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ipv6.fastweb.it%2Fdownload-gogoclient.html&edit-text=) (translated for courtesy) says to install gogo6 client and use the magic `tsp.ipv6.fastweb.it` server.

Since the user guide is well dated and Windows 8.1 is quite recent, I have the suspect that there is a way to follow that Fastweb guide without actually installing new software into the system.

Unfortunately, I can't ask this question in a more specific way (e.g. "how to setup 4to6 tunnel in Win8?") because I actually **don't know** what protocol does that `tsp.ipv6.fastweb.it` server use

Answer (score 0):

Gogo6 uses the [Tunnel Setup Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunnel_Setup_Protocol) on UDP port 3653 to set up an IPv6 tunnel. The actual parameters will be provided by Fastweb's server, and once you have those to hand, you probably should be able to manually configure the tunnel yourself.

Keep in mind that this is meant to be a short-term, transitional technology; not a permanent deployment. As such, I'm surprised that Fastweb is doing it this way. In 2015 there's no excuse for not deploying native dual stack (and hasn't been a good excuse for years now).

Comment: Agree. There's no excuse for dual-stack but there is no interest in investing in a transition no customer is currently demanding. Because for home ISPs, customers are ignorant people that spend their days taking selfies and swiping candies in a popular mobile game :-) Do you require IPv6 for that? No.

Comment: Facebook is on IPv6, along with Google, most of the top websites, and some online games, so using an IPv6 transition technology can actually make the customers' experience worse. Gamers will have worse latency and increased jitter, for instance.

Comment: Back to the question, you answered the part about identifying the protocol. Is there any way to natively set up such `TSP` protocol on Windows 8?

Comment: In a word, no. Windows does not include a TSP client.